# Problemas com ui:repeat e ajax update

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

Boa noite.

Estou com alguns problemas para usar o `ui:repeat` e o ajax update do primefaces.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha intenção é listar os critérios a partir do id do Processo de Decisão a que eles estão vinculados para que o usuário possa selecionar, para cada um destes, se é um valor numérico (checkbox booleano) e, dependendo da seleção do check, renderizar se é um valor numérico (spinner) ou impacto (selectOneMenu).

Os problemas são:

1°) Não está listando as coisas com o `ui:repeat`. Eu depurei e constatei que os valores da lista estão sendo preenchidos.

2°) Não sei porque, mas todas as vezes que mudo o Processo de Decisão, ele fecha o diálogo (talvez porque dei update em todo form?)

3°) Por que o espaço do selectOneMenu veio assim? Não deveria ser todo branco até o ícone de clique para abrir a lista?

**View**

```
                <p:panelGrid style="width: 100%;">
                    <p:row> 
                        <p:column><h:outputLabel for="pdMenu" value="Processo de Decisão: " class="componentePF label" /></p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:selectOneMenu id="pdMenu" converter="generic" value="#{topsisBean.pd}" style="width:100% !important;" 
                                class="componentePF text" required="true" requiredMessage="É necessário escolher um processo de decisão">
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Escolha um Processo" noSelectionOption="true" />
                                <f:selectItems value="#{topsisBean.pds}" var="pd" itemLabel="#{pd.nomePD}"  
                                    itemValue="#{pd}" converter="generic" />
                                <p:ajax listener="#{topsisBean.mudouPD}" update=":form" />
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>

                    <p:row> 
                        <p:column><h:outputLabel for="projetoMenu" value="Projeto: " class="componentePF label" onclick="#{topsisBean.getProjetosPD()}"/></p:column>
                        <p:column>
                            <p:selectOneMenu id="projetoMenu" converter="generic" value="#{topsisBean.avaliaProjeto.projeto}" 
                                class="componentePF text" required="true" requiredMessage="É necessário escolher um projeto">
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Escolha um Projeto" itemDisabled="true" noSelectionOption="true" />
                                <f:selectItems value="#{topsisBean.projetosPD}" var="p" itemLabel="#{p.nomeProjeto}" itemValue="#{p}" converter="generic" />
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>
                </p:panelGrid>

                <p:panelGrid style="width: 100%;" id="avaliaProjetoGrid" rendered="#{topsisBean.pd != null}">
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column><h:outputText value="Critério" class="componentePF label"/></p:column>
                        <p:column><h:outputText value="Valor Numérico" class="componentePF label"/></p:column>                          
                        <p:column><h:outputText value="Valor ou Impacto" class="componentePF label"/></p:column>
                    </p:row>

                    <ui:repeat var="a" value="#{topsisBean.avaliaProjetosPD}">
                        <p:row>
                            <p:column><h:outputText value="#{a.criterio.nomeCriterio}" class="componentePF label"/></p:column>

                            <p:column>
                                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox label="Sim" widgetVar="flag">
                                    <p:ajax update="valor escalaMenu"/>
                                </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column>
                                <p:selectOneMenu id="escalaMenu" converter="generic" value="#{a.escala}" rendered="#{!flag}"
                                    class="componentePF text" required="true" requiredMessage="É necessário escolher uma escala">
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Escolha um Impacto de Escala" itemDisabled="true" noSelectionOption="true" />
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{topsisBean.escalas}" var="e" itemLabel="#{e.impactoEscala}" itemValue="#{e}" converter="generic" />
                                </p:selectOneMenu>

                                <p:spinner id="valor" value="#{a.valor}" class="componentePF text" rendered="#{flag}"/>
                            </p:column>
                        </p:row>
                    </ui:repeat>
                </p:panelGrid>
        </p:dialog>
```

**Métodos do bean utilizados**

```
public void mudouPD() {
    projetosPD = projetoDAO.listar(pd);
    setaAvaliaProjetosPD();
}

public void setaAvaliaProjetosPD() {
    criterios = criterioDAO.listar(pd);
    avaliaProjetosPD = new ArrayList<>();
    AvaliaProjeto a;

    for(Criterio c : criterios) {
        a = new AvaliaProjeto();
        a.setCriterio(c);

        avaliaProjetosPD.add(a);
    }
}
```

Se precisarem do pojo, me avisem que edito com eles.

Comment: Ninguém tem ideia do que posso fazer? :(

Comment: Cara, da uma olhada no seu log, provavelmente ta acontecendo um erro aqui. "<p:ajax update="valor escalaMenu"/>" quando você utiliza o ui:repeat, para cada <p:column> ele vai dar um id diferente, então não vai mais existir um "escalaMenu" e por isso não deve estar listando as coisas.

Comment: Opa Albsilva. Testei aqui mas não funcionou. Tem alguma outra ideia do que possa ser?

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi o problema substituindo o segundo panelGrid por uma tabela comum do html.